# PayPal: "The email address for the business is not present in the encrypted blob. Please contact your merchant". How to fix?

Tags: paypal

My code for my PayPal integration has worked for a decade or so with no problems.

Today I've generated a new public certificate as the old one was due to expire.  I did it exactly the same (documented) way that I've always done it, and uploaded it to PayPal.  Stupidly, I deleted the old one before testing the new one.

And now I get this message when I try to make a purchase:

```
The email address for the business is not present in the encrypted blob. Please contact your merchant.
```

Any idea what's happened?  My only thought is that PayPal are trying to force me into using a more modern way of integrating their payment gateway with my site, and are giving this error based on me having a newer public cerficiate now.  But PayPal, if that's really what it's about, have a link to a help article on the subject FFS!

I'm stumped, any suggestions welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have this problem it might be worth checking the file permissions of your new private key.  Mine was 600 and needed to be changed to 644 to match the old outgoing file.  Problem solved.